# Android Studio How to check which Imageview has clicked and assign an Int value to it?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

**ActivityOne**

I have 12 Imageviews. User click on either 1 of them. 
If they click ImageView 1, we assign a int value to it (image_id=1; )

**ActivityTwo**

Use a If else statement to check which image has they clicked

```
Intent result_intent=getIntent();

    if (image_id==1) {
        text.setText("U have clicked image "+image_id);
    }
```

**I need the int value in ActivityTwo as I need to calculate sth.**  Anyone can help? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gosulove

`setOnClickListener` on your all `ImageViews`

Like this In your Activity 1

```
ImageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView3.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView4.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView5.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView6.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView7.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView8.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView9.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView10.setOnClickListener(this);
// like this for all 10 ImageViews
```

Now inside your `onClick()` method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       int image_id;
       swtich v.getId() {
        case R.id.ImageView1 :
             image_id = 1;
             break;
        case R.id.ImageView2 :
             image_id = 2;
             break;
        // like this for all your imageviews
        case R.id.ImageView10 :
             image_id = 10;
             break;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
        intent.putExtra("IMAGE_ID", image_id);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
```

In your Activity2

```
int image_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE_ID", 0);
text.setText("U have clicked image "+image_id);
```

Comment: Hello, can you edit the above coding for activity one to be more precise?  "setOnClickListener on your all ImageViews" can you type out the full coding for it? Thx alot

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    //do your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In ActivityOne, pass the value in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtra("IMAGE_ID", imageId);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ActivityTwo, get the value in this way:

```
int image_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE_ID", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to pass the value to Activity2.

In Activity1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("image_id", image_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity2:

```
String image_id = getIntent.getIntExtra("image_id");
```

[more detail](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You  can setOnClickListener on each imageView. In `onClick(View v)` method check the id of each imageview. that is in this way:

```
ImageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
ImageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Now you have to implements `View.OnClickListener` interface. After implementing this you have this method:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId()==R.id.ImageView1){
               image_id=1;
       Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
       intent.putExtra("IMAGE_ID", image_id);
       startActivity(intent);
             }else  if(v.getId()==R.id.ImageView2){
               image_id=2;
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
       intent.putExtra("IMAGE_ID", image_id);
       startActivity(intent);
             }
       }
```

Hope this will help you :)

**Edit:**
for more about in button click visit [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/)

Comment: Hello, can you edit the above coding for activity one to be more precise ? I am new to setOnClickListener. Thx!