# Check to see if ImageView is equal to input click

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, imageview

I am wanting to create an Android app (using Android Studio) whereby a user will see a random image that I've generated in an array. They then have to select the correct image from a horizontal scroll view that corresponds to the random image that was displayed.
However, I can not seem to write the correct code to check whether the user has clicked on the correct, corresponding image. I am using an if-statement.

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="205dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/face_with_tears_of_joy"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            android:onClick="clickedFaceWithTearsOfJoy"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/face_with_tears_of_joy" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grinning_face"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            android:onClick="clickedGrinningFace"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/grinning_face" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            android:onClick="clickedGrinningFaceWithSmilingEyes"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rolling_on_the_floor_laughing"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/rolling_on_the_floor_laughing" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smiling_face_with_open_mouth"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/smiling_face_with_open_mouth" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_cold_sweat"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_cold_sweat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_smiling_eyes"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/funny_emoji"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_smiling_eyes" />




    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ImageView imageView;
public Random random;
public TextView textView;
int easy[] = {R.drawable.face_with_tears_of_joy, R.drawable.grinning_face, R.drawable.grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes};
int hard[] = {R.drawable.face_with_tears_of_joy, R.drawable.grinning_face, R.drawable.grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes,
        R.drawable.rolling_on_the_floor_laughing, R.drawable.smiling_face_with_open_mouth, R.drawable.smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_cold_sweat,
        R.drawable.smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_smiling_eyes};
public ImageView imageView1;
public ImageView imageView2;
public ImageView imageView3;
public ImageView imageView4;
public ImageView imageView5;
public ImageView imageView6;
public ImageView imageView7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.face_with_tears_of_joy);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grinning_face);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes);
    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rolling_on_the_floor_laughing);
    imageView5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.smiling_face_with_open_mouth);
    imageView6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_cold_sweat);
    imageView7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.smiling_face_with_open_mouth_and_smiling_eyes);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    random = new Random();
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    int randomInt = random.nextInt(hard.length);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(hard[randomInt]);

}

    public void clickedEmoji(View view) {

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view;

        Bitmap clicked = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Bitmap displayed = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        if (clicked == displayed) {
            textView.setText("Well Done!");
        } else {
            textView.setText("Unlucky!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making multiple functions, I would just combine them all into one. Also, the code you created is comparing an ImageView with a Drawable, which is an invalid comparison. Instead, you can do the following.

```
public void clickedImage(View view) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
    Bitmap clicked = drawableToBitmap(image.getDrawable());
    Bitmap displayed = drawableToBitmap(imageView.getBackground());
    if (clicked == displayed) {
        textView.setText("Well Done!");
    } else {
        textView.setText("Unlucky!");
    }
}

public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable d) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    d.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Then, for each ImageView in your XML file, just add `android:onClick="clickedImage"`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it not compiling or is the functionality broken?

Comment: It is compiling and running on the emulator. However, the textView I created - which is where certain text is displayed after the user has clicked a drawable and whether the selected drawable matches the displayed one - is not showing. Also, getDrawable is deprecated. I have tried to play around with the getResources etc and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If user clicks on a drawable, it must check to see whether the (imageview) they clicked on is the same as the one
being displayed

Comment: Ok, try the new edit. I misunderstood your question before, but now it checks whether the image displayed has the same drawable s the image clicked.

Comment: Your new, edited code is half-working. Whenever I click on the drawable, it changes the text to "Well Done" no matter what, even if the drawable is the incorrect drawable

Comment: It turns out that there is a special way to compare drawables, I have updated my answer to use this.

Comment: Whichever Drawable I click, `textView` is displaying "Well Done!". Even if I click the incorrect drawable, it still displays that. I've been looking all over the Internet for hours and I cannot seem to get this to work

Comment: I have edited my post, and put in the latest Java code

Comment: There is a flaw in your code. In your clickedEmoji function, displayed should be taking the drawable from imageView, not image.

Comment: Ahhh, I do not understand completely. So how would I have to write my`clickedEmoji` function?

Comment: You made an error while copying my code. Just rewrite `Bitmap displayed = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` as `Bitmap displayed = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

Comment: I've just changed my code to the correction, but now it crashes at runtime with `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference` I think we're getting closer though

Comment: Ok, just edited. I incorrectly assumed that your Drawables were BitmapDrawables.

Comment: Now I get this error at runtime `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference` at this line `Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` and this line of code `Bitmap displayed = drawableToBitmap(imageView.getDrawable());`

Comment: You are setting the background at the top, so you must do `getBackground()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, now it says "Unlucky" no matter which Drawable I select. Thank you for your help, but maybe its just not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to either implement OnClickListener and  just set OnClickListener to every image you want to check that have been clicked.
Check this link it might be helpful..
[Android Studio How to check which Imageview has clicked and assign an Int value to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365157/android-studio-how-to-check-which-imageview-has-clicked-and-assign-an-int-value)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, because I am not creating an intent and passing to another Activity